# Overfitting models in mlr3

Tags: r, machine-learning, predictive-models, confusion-matrix, mlr

I'm trying to compare multiple learners on my dataset (called "data") in order to predict a target called "lesionResponse", with custom resampling. Since mlr3 package doesn't allow to group and stratify at the same time, I used a customized resampling in order to avoir the leakage of datas between sets. There is also a ratio of 3 for the 0/1 modalities of my target. Here is a short example of my dataset :

```
structure(list(PatientID = c("P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "P5", "P5", "P5", "P5", "P6", "P6", "P6"), 
    LesionResponse = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L),.Label = c("0", 
    "1"), class = "factor"), F1 = c(1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 
    0.625, 0.625, 0.625, 0.625, 0.625, 0.625, 1.25, 0.625, 0.625, 
    1.25, 1.25, 1.25), F2 = c(1, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1, 6, 9, 0, 5, 0, 4, 4, 4, 5, 2, 1, 1), F3 = c(0, 4, 3, 1, 1, 0, 3, 8, 4, 5, 0, 4, 4, 3, 5, 2, 0, 0), F4 = c(0, 9, 0, 7, 4, 0, 3, 8, 4, 5, 9, 1, 1, 3, 5, 3, 9, 0)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L), class = "data.frame")
```

I manually splited the datas in train, validation, and test sets, with inner and outer resampling for the analyse :

```
data
data$weights = ifelse(data$LesionResponse == "1", 3, 1)
task = as_task_classif(data, target = "LesionResponse")
task$set_col_roles("weights", roles = "weight")

# Création du OUTER resampling via customisation
resampling_outer = rsmp("custom")
resampling_outer$instantiate(task, train = list(train_rows_outer), test = list(test_rows))

#Création du INNER resampling via customisation
resampling_inner = rsmp("custom")
resampling_inner$instantiate(task, train = list(train_rows), test = list(valid_rows))
```

Explanation :
data = my dataset

outer resampling = I divide my entire dataset into
train_rows_outer and test_rows for final prediction and benchmark.

Inner resampling = Inside the train_rows_outer, I created a train and a valid sets to tune the parameters of my models.

Here are my models :
-ranger
-rpart
-svm
-knn
-xgboost

I'll just post two of them to show the code :

```
#Auto tuning Ranger
learner_ranger = lrn("classif.ranger", predict_type = "prob", num.trees = to_tune(1, 2000), mtry.ratio = to_tune(0, 1), sample.fraction = to_tune(1e-1, 1))

rr_ranger = tune_nested(
  tuner = tnr("grid_search", resolution = 5),
  task = task,
  learner = learner_ranger,
  inner_resampling = resampling_inner,
  outer_resampling = resampling_outer,
  measure = msr("classif.ce"),
  term_evals = 20,
  store_models = TRUE,
  terminator = trm("none")
)

rr_ranger$score()[, .(iteration, task_id, learner_id, resampling_id, classif.ce)]
predictions = rr_ranger$prediction()
predictions$confusion

        truth
response   0   1
       0 163  65
       1   0   0
```

```
#Auto tuning svm
learner_svm = lrn("classif.svm", type = "C-classification", cost = to_tune(p_dbl(1e-5, 1e5, logscale = TRUE)), gamma = to_tune(p_dbl(1e-5, 1e5, logscale = TRUE)), kernel = to_tune(c("polynomial", "radial")), degree = to_tune(1, 4))

rr_svm = tune_nested(
  tuner = tnr("grid_search", resolution = 10),
  task = task,
  learner = learner_svm,
  inner_resampling = resampling_inner,
  outer_resampling = resampling_outer,
  measure = msr("classif.ce"),
  term_evals = 20,
  store_models = TRUE,
  terminator = trm("none")
)

extract_inner_tuning_results(rr_svm)[, .SD, .SDcols = !c("learner_param_vals", "x_domain")]
extract_inner_tuning_archives(rr_svm, unnest = NULL, exclude_columns = c("resample_result", "uhash", "x_domain", "timestamp"))

rr_svm$score()[, .(iteration, task_id, learner_id, resampling_id, classif.ce)]
predictions = rr_svm$prediction()
predictions$confusion

        truth
response   0   1
       0 163  65
       1   0   0
```

Even with the weights added, the normalization, the feature selection, I have all my models predicting the majority modality of my set. Could the problem be In my code or my choice of classif ?? Would another metric be better ?

Comment: You have a $3$:$1$ imbalance in your labels, correct?

Comment: @Dave yes indeed. To be more precise in my full set I have nearly 800 "0" and 270 "1". Concerning my question, I'm wondering if the reason is because I tune my models based on the classif.ce...I'll try with F1 and come back editing the post with the results

Comment: Some of the trouble with looking at the mode classifications is that they require a threshold for binning the continuous predictions into discrete categories, and the software default for that threshold might be totally inappropriate for your work. One metric that is totally separate from the threshold is the ROCAUC. How does those perform on ROCAUC? It might be that your mode is quite good at distinguishing between the categories and wild score high accuracy at a different threshold.